# Numpy slicing with list

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing

I'm trying to slice an Ndarray `a` with a list `b`. But the behaviour is not as I would expect it. What do I have to change to get the wanted result?

```
a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

b = [2,2]
```

Actual behaviour:

```
a[:,b]

array([[[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Wanted behaviour:

```
a[:,2,2]

array([ 8, 17, 26])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `:` with `slice(None`) and unpacking `b`:

```
a[(slice(None), *b)]
# [ 8 17 26]
```

---

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))
b = [2, 2]
result = a[(slice(None), *b)]

print(result)
# [ 8 17 26]
print((result == a[:, 2, 2]).all())
# True
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works perfectly! ```
a[(slice(None), *b)]) ``` has one bracket too much at the end.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to strip the trailing parenthesis.